# Children of a DBus Object

Tags: python, dbus

I'm trying to write a dbus object that exports users and have created my object at /path/to/users. This object has signals such as 'user-added', 'user-removed' etc.

I then want to provide access to each of these users at /path/to/users/[a, b, c] for users a, b and c which will have some methods for each user.

My question though is how do i 'list' the path /path/to/users to return a, b, c?

Is my only option returning an array of paths from path.to.users.ListUsers(), is there a standard interface i can inherit, or some form of introspection?

Thanks.

nb. I'm doing this in python but i think the question is language independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [standard D-Bus Introspectable interface](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-introspectable) provides a method to introspect an object; the [data returned by it](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#introspection-format) includes a list of objects.

Most D-Bus bindings, including `dbus-python`, implement `Introspectable` on the service-side for you; so your client should be able to call the `Introspect` method on the object at `/path/to/users` to see which user objects exist. I don't know offhand if `dbus-python` provides a nicer interface to this data. Personally, I would implement a `ListUsers()` method, which returns `a{oa{sv}}`—that is, a list of object paths, along with some properties about those objects (say, the equivalent of calling `Properties.GetAll("uk.co.example.MyService.User")` on each object).

(If you're interested in the future, David Zeuthan has [proposed](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.freedesktop.dbus/13751) standardizing something like this.)